# How to compare two objects without sorting in java

Tags: java, comparison, compare

I am trying to compare to objects without sorting them. I just want the sign of "value" to change.
this is not a code, just the idea.

```
public S(double value, SOME s1, SOME s2){
 v=value;
 src1= s1;
 src2 =s2;
}
```

The SOME data type has a an array in its class.
SOME is a java class that has an array, and passes the value of the s1, and s2.
Assigns s1, and s2 as a value for the array.

if src1 < src2, v would be negative,  else it would be positive.
 What
 method or class should I use?

Comment: This question is *way* too vague to answer. If `v` is meant to be the result of the comparison, why is it being passed into a constructor? Where do you want to put the comparison code? What is `S`? What do you mean by "without sorting them"? (Sorting is usually performed on a collection.) What does `src1 < src2` mean - how do you want to compare the two? Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface in your SOME class and override the compareTo method.

Something like:

```
@Override 
public int compareTo(SOME s1) {
//compare objects here and return the int
}
```

Here is a [link](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=10) with an example

Comment: Do i need to declare an instance variable in java class file S, so that when I compare ns1 with ns2, I will only access the integers?